# How to reduce size of image before storing into database in c#

Tags: c#

I have code to convert image before storing into database
Due this image is store but its size is not changes so my database is become too large
Help to reduce its size

please my code is in my first comment

Comment: my code is    void convertImage()
        {
            if (image_pictureBox.Image != null)
            {
                ms = new MemoryStream();
                image_pictureBox.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                byte[] photo_array = new byte[ms.Length];
                ms.Position = 0;
                ms.Read(photo_array, 0, photo_array.Length);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A_IMAGE", photo_array);
            }
        }

Comment: Do you need to change size and all?

Comment: Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31781799/edit) button of your question to update your question. Please also include exactly *what* is the problem and what you have done so far to try and fix it

Comment: Why wouldn't storing the image within the file system and storing the path to the image within the DB work?

Comment: yes ... its size should reduce because my database is become too heavy if i directly save image

Comment: i have already done all project with path but i want to store image in  database directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good variant to resize image:

```
    /// <summary> 
    /// Reduce image by reducing quality
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="path"> Initially img. </param> 
    /// <param name="quality"> An integer from 0 to 100, with 100 being the highest quality. </param> 
    public static Image ReduceImg(Image img, int quality)
    {
        if (quality < 0 || quality > 100)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Quality is between 0 and 100");

        // Encoder parameter for image quality 
        EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality);
        // JPEG image codec 
        ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
        EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(stream, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
            var b = new Bitmap(stream);
            return new Bitmap(b);
        }
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Returns the image codec with the given mime type 
    /// </summary> 
    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
    {
        // Get image codecs for all image formats 
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

        // Find the correct image codec 
        for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++)
            if (codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType)
                return codecs[i];

        return null;
    }
```

Use:

```
var yourNewImage = ReduceImg(yourImage, 50); // 50 for example. It's quality of new image
```